# Delphi: How to encode TIdBytes to Base64 string?

Tags: string, delphi, base64, ansistring

How to encode TIdBytes to Base64 string (not AnsiString) ?

```
  ASocket.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(5);

  if not ASocket.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    ASocket.Socket.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(data);
    // here I need to encode data to base64 string, how ? I don't need AnsiString!!
    // var s:string;
    s := EncodeBase64(data, Length(data)); // but it will be AnsiString :(
```

Or how to send AnsiString via AContext.Connection.Socket.Write() ?

Compiler saying **Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'**

"data" variable contains UTF-8 data from website.

Comment: Maybe there is other way to pass binary data to string ? Which will have more performance than base64 encoding..

Comment: Compiler telling me that there maybe data lose

Comment: in variable "data" I have UTF-8 data from website.

Comment: Ok, if I trying to send ansistring AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(s); the compiler is saying: W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Indy's `TIdEncoderMIME` class to encode `String`, `TStream`, and `TIdByte` data to base64 (and `TIdDecoderMIME` to decode from base64 back to `String`, `TStream`, or `TIdBytes`), eg:

```
s := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(data);
```

As for sending `AnsiString` data, Indy in D2009+ simply does not have any `TIdIOHandler.Write()` overloads for handling `AnsiString` data at all, only `UnicodeString` data.  To send an `AnsiString` as-is, you can either:

1) copy the `AnsiString` into a `TIdBytes` using `RawToBytes()` and then call `TIdIOHandler.Write(TIdBytes)`:

```
var
  as: AnsiString;
begin
  as := ...;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(as[1], Length(as)));
end;
```

2) copy the `AnsiString` data into a `TStream` and then call `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)`:

```
var
  as: AnsiString;
  strm: TStream;
begin
  strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    strm.WriteBuffer(as[1], Length(as));
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(strm);
  finally
    strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
var
  as: AnsiString;
  strm: TStream;
begin
  as := ...;
  strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(as[1], Length(as));
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(strm);
  finally
    strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @waza123: like this: `data := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes(s);`

Answer (score 3):

In later versions of Delphi with Unicode string as the default...you should be safe to simply cast the return value as a String to rid yourself of that warning.  Base64 only returns a small set of values (ascii) ... which will never lead to data loss in conversion to Unicode.

```
s := String(EncodeBase64(data, Length(data)));
```

Comment: So after I receive the encoded string(base64) , is it safe to past it to DecodeBase64(AnsiString(s)) ?